# SQL Server 2008 - Search Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not a SQL Expert. I’m trying to elegantly solve a query problem that others have had to have had.  Surprisingly, Google is not returning anything that is helping. Basically, my application has a “search” box. This search field will allow a user to search for customers in the system.  I have a table called “Customer” in my SQL Server 2008 database.  This table is defined as follows:

**Customer**

- UserName (nvarchar)
- FirstName (nvarchar)
- LastName (nvarchar)

As you can imagine, my users will enter queries of varying cases and probably mis-spell the customer’s names regularly. How do I query my customer table and return the 25 results that are closest to their query? I have no idea how to do this ranking and consider the three fields listed in my table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest [full-text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Full-text search will provide plenty of options for dealing with some name variants and can rank the "closeness" of the results using `CONTAINSTABLE`. If you find that full-text search is not sufficient, you might consider a third-party indexing tool like Lucene.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) or [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753(v=SQL.100).aspx) as an alternative to full text search.

```
SELECT TOP 25 UserName, FirstName, LastName
FROM Customer
WHERE DIFFERENCE( UserName, @SearchValue ) > 2
ORDER BY DIFFERENCE( UserName, @SearchValue ), UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

The case issue you can solve easy by setting your table collation to be case insensitive

The misspelling not sure how to handle but have a look at the [full text search capabilities of sql server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)..